# REGULAR EXPRESSIONS IN SQL AND SNOWFLAKE

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a string and I want to remove all the digits and punctuations from the end of the string. I doing this on Snowflake

STRING:

```
1234 Pharmacy #344455
Hy-Vee Pharmacy #2 (1658)
```

DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
1234 Pharmacy
Hy-Vee Pharmacy
```

Comment: Hi, you can try this,select TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE('1234 Pharmacy #344455', '[0-9#]')) as new_col ;

Comment: This removes all digits, I want to retain the initial ones

Comment: Do they all start with an #?

Answer (score 0):

Using REGEXP_REPLACE:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('1234 Pharmacy #344455', '(\\W|\\d)*$') 
-- 1234 Pharmacy

SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('Hy-Vee Pharmacy #2 (1658)', '(\\W|\\d)*$') 
-- Hy-Vee Pharmacy
```

Comment: Also If I have slightly different combination too like 
Hy-Vee Pharmacy #2 (1658)

I also want to output this as Hy-Vee Pharmacy
with the above regex, how can I do that

Comment: @user11644013 `SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('Hy-Vee Pharmacy #2 (1658)', '(\\W|\\d)*$') `